# Strange scripting changes between Adobe CS6 and CC--need some workarounds

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, creative-cloud

Our company has been using Adobe Creative Suite 6 up until now. We have some very long, in-depth JavaScript scripts that we use with InDesign CS6 and Illustrator CS6. We are in the process of moving from CS6 to the Creative Cloud and we've noticed two major issues with how our scripts run in CC:

1. When an InDesign script calls Illustrator by way of BridgeTalk, the script pauses until Illustrator is made the *foreground* application. That is, I have to actually **click** on the Illustrator dock icon or **task-switch** over to Illustrator from InDesign before the script continues doing what it does. While this isn't a *huge* problem, it *does* slow us down and adds an extra manual step into what *should* be a completely automated process.
2. One of our InDesign scripts opens an .indd file, does a bunch of work on it, then it's supposed to save it (over the existing file) and close it. With InDesign CC now, sometimes it throws up a "Save" dialog when it should just save the file silently. When the script is run in InDesign CS6, the file is saved silently without any problem. Again, this adds another manual step into what should be automated and hands-off. Admittedly, the location to which the file is being saved is on a network drive, but again, InDesign CS6 never gave us any problem with that.

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround for these new issues that Creative Cloud has brought upon us?

**2014-11-03 @ 2:51pm EDIT:** I just discovered that the `Document.save()` method takes a boolean argument that can *force* the save. If anyone else is having issues with this, check out [The Jongware guide](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Document.html#save) for details on how to use that argument.

However, I do still need that first issue resolved. Any ideas?

Comment: Shall I assume you're using `BridgeTalk.bringToFront('illustrator')`? I've seen that this is broken for some CC apps. I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Actually, I was unaware of such a method. I just now tried to use that as the first line of the Illustrator portion of the script after it is called through BridgeTalk, and voila! That seems to have taken care of it for me. If you want to post that suggestion as an answer to my question, I'll give you credit by marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: As for your issue with `BridgeTalk.bringToFront()` not working for some CC apps, I only have a need to run BridgeTalk between InDesign and Illustrator, so I don't know about the other apps. If I have some free time here at work (which doesn't seem likely, unfortunately), I'll give it a shot with a few of the other CC apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
BridgeTalk.bringToFront('illustrator');
```

as a means to bring Illustrator to the front. There are other parameters (see the JavaScript Tools Guide http://www.adobe.com/jp/joc/incopy/scripting/pdfs/JavaScript_Tools_Guide_CS4.pdf), but you should be able to use the simplest form as shown above.